# What software alternatives are there to ECC storage under Linux Mint 21 and LMDE5 to protect against a bit flip problem?

Tags: linux-mint, software-rec, software-raid, ecc

It is known that there are other approaches besides ECC memory that can help avoid data loss due to e.g. flipping of RAM memory cells by cosmic rays (bit flip problem):

What the Bit Flip Problem is:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230114090442/https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/01/linus-torvalds-blames-intel-for-lack-of-ecc-ram-in-consumer-pcs/

Error correction procedure:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230114220121/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction
- https://www-tecchannel-de.translate.goog/a/fehlertoleranter-speicher-schuetzt-vor-systemausfaellen-und-datenverlust,402181,4?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp

BIOS implementations of RAM Mirroring:

- https://www-thomas--krenn-com.translate.goog/de/wiki/RAM_Mirroring?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp
- https://web.archive.org/web/20230114220407/https://www-thomas--krenn-com.translate.goog/de/wiki/RAM_Mirroring?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Software implementations:

- https://www-admin--magazin-de.translate.goog/Das-Heft/2013/12/Speicherfehler-unter-Linux-erkennen-und-beobachten?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp

SoftECC

https://web.archive.org/web/20230119082028/https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/softecc:ddopson-meng/softecc_ddopson-meng.pdf
https://web.archive.org/web/20230114103624/https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/softecc%3Addopson-meng/softecc_ddopson-meng.pdf

What software solutions, such as kernel implementations or add-on programs, will be usable under Linux Mint21 and LMDE5 in 2023? Possibly a end to end hash useing technology comparable to ZFS RAIDZ, but for working RAM memory and not for hard disks.

## Hints for possible actual solutions:

## Mirrored memory support:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230114231952/https://lwn.net/Articles/897734/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20230114232055/https://www.fujitsu.com/jp/documents/products/software/os/linux/catalog/LinuxConJapan2016-Izumi.pdf
- https://web.archive.org/web/20230114232143/https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-AArch64-Mirrored-Memory
- https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/nand-flash/tn2971_software_bch_ecc_on_linux.pdf
- https://linux.kernel.narkive.com/cxqgDQlR/software-based-ecc
- https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/36769

Comment: This is an English forum, it'd help if you could provide sources in English instead of German.

Comment: Fixed now. Thanks

Comment: Hi Eddy! I'm sorry, but the first sentence of my answer kind of explains why there's no sensible chance of you finding what you're looking for. The bounty will have a hard time changing that :(

Answer (score 3):

Basically, in any meaningful manner, you need hardware support to fix memory errors, because your CPU is not designed to do any error checking or addition of error-correction information: software assumes the data out reads from RAM is correct.

When software reads a value from RAM, it does so by telling your CPU with some "load" instruction that it wants to get some location from memory. (That is very different to what happens when you read data from ZFS)

As operating system or other software, you stand very little chance intercepting that read in unmodified software - all you could do is make *every* userland read fail, then load the appropriate pages from memory, do your error checking, and finally return the value; that works exactly one every 4kB page on your system, unless you discard the lookup table that translates virtual memory addresses to linear memory addresses every single time, and invalidate all caches. The result would be that your system would be super slow - we're talking pentium 1 here, as most advantages in speed come from exactly not doing that. If you want a very slow machine with error-checked memory, I'm sure there's hardware recyclers that will cut you a nice deal on legacy server hardware with ECC RAM!

The SoftECC paper presents a solution that really doesn't apply to any real world problem: you need to implement the "stale memory page checking" (it can't secure pages that are frequently written to, although due to proximity effects, these are actually the ones you need to protect, see e.g. Row hammer) in Linux yourself (good luck with that on a modern system) and you still get enormous performance downsides.

Now, if instead you're considering actually modifying your software to contain integrity checking itself, that would work. For example, assume you're essentially writing a database server with huge amounts of data cache in RAM - you could easily implement checksums and correction in that yourself. But then the question becomes a development and channel coding problem für a specific application, not some generic RAM protection scheme for all the software running on your system.

Honestly, ECC is built in to the current generation of desktop CPUs, many Mainboards support it, and ECC RAM is not that immensely more expensive: if you need ECC, hardware is the right place to implement that, from an architectural point of view, not software.

Comment: Its looks for me, hardware RAM ECC are unknown on Notebooks... But if I remember right, they are firmware based implementations and they are a linux kernel implementation since some time... The implementation is related to a new version of UEFI...

Comment: There is SO-DIMMs with ECC, so I'm not sure that this is true. But considering modern non-ECC RAM is not *that* unreliable, I wonder whether a workload that would actually benefit from ECC wouldn't be much better off on a workstation PC or in a VM in a datacenter.

Comment: No, UEFI had absolutely no bearing on intercepting memory transaction. You must have misread something, I think. If you can find a reference, I'd be interested, but honestly, not a firmware job. And not an operating system job, either. (You might need a modern firmware to enable the hardware ECC, that's what I could imagine being stated)

Comment: If I remember right, the uefi and kernel related solution is Huwai, Fujitsu and one more company based. The kernel implementation was about 5.4

Comment: References, please. This really sounds like a misunderstanding, so please understand me doubting your memory here

Comment: I added the 3 sources now, which I have seen.

Comment: Mirrored memory is a hardware feature - observe how the phoronix article says that the server hardware provides the functionality. The admin magazine link you posted describes how to interact with the memory controller hardware to read hardware ECC information, not about software ECC at all. I'll have to read the Fujitsu thing, but this isn't a great track record in Quellenarbeit ;)

Comment: Yeah Fujitsu presentation slide 3: feature of the xeon processor/its memory controller. So none of this is software ECC. You just need software support to make use of the hardware ECC/RAM mirroring.